# Python trigger function to raise exception without modifying it

Tags: python, exception

With the code block:

```
1  import re
2  import sys
3  import traceback
4 
5  def foo(arg):
6      if isinstance(arg, dict):
7         return arg.get('key', 0)
8      return 0
9  
10 arg = {}
11
12
13
14 try:
15     foo(arg)
16 except Exception:
17     lines = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
18     for line in lines:
19         m = re.match(r'  File .*, line (\d+), in foo\n.*\n', line)
20         if m and int(m.group(1)) < 5:
21             print("Foo threw!")
22             sys.exit()
23     raise
24 else:
25     sys.stderr.write("foo did not throw!")
```

The question is: can I add some code logic between line 10-14, thus make the final code control flow can reach at line **21**, where `Foo threw!` got printed out ? Attention that, codes between line 1-10 and after line 14 can NOT be modified.

I was tried to write another function to raise an exception, replace `foo()` with it, it didn't work since the `if` at line 20, which test against `< 5`, "protect" the exception happened before line 5.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking us to write code to place between lines 10 and 14? If so, what have you tried and just where is your difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

No, because these lines:

```
m = re.match(r'  File .*, line (\d+), in foo\n.*\n', line)
if m and int(m.group(1)) < 5
```

mean that the error must happen in lines 1-4 which come before `foo`, so it's not even possible if you add an error to the first line of `foo`.

Comment: thanks, how about I move `def foo(arg):` to line 4 ?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't think an error can be thrown at the `def` line.